# hyperref package - Change the style of the Bookmarks - add a text label

Tags: hyperref

Using the [`\hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package I would like to add the word **Chapter** before the chapter numbers, as shown in the image below. For example, instead of "1 Wish It" I would like to have "Chapter 1: Wish It". Is this possible? I add my starter code below.

[image: Adding text to Bookmarks]

Starter code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfauthor={Brian Griffin},
    pdftitle={Wish it, Want it, Do it},
    pdfsubject={Self help},
    pdfkeywords={therapy,healing,chicken soup},
    pdfproducer={Penguin Publishing}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wish It}
What are all the things you want most in the world?

Use the following pages to write down all of your dreams and desires.

\blindtext

\chapter{Want It}    
\blindtext

\chapter{Do It}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following trick redefines `\thechapter` to output the prefix for the bookmarks:

```
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
```

The second argument of `\texorpdfstring` is only processed, when the string is prepared for the bookmarks (PDF strings).

Full example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfauthor={Brian Griffin},
    pdftitle={Wish it, Want it, Do it},
    pdfsubject={Self help},
    pdfkeywords={therapy,healing,chicken soup},
    pdfproducer={Penguin Publishing}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Wish It}
What are all the things you want most in the world?

\section{Test section}

Use the following pages to write down all of your dreams and desires.

\blindtext

\chapter{Want It}
\blindtext

\chapter{Do It}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Many thanks, this works great! How did you get the small icons in the example output above? I can't find this in the manual.

Comment: @John The symbols are coming from the PDF viewer (Adobe Acrobat Reader).